# Must a 12V to 110V switched-capacitor inverter output be isolated? if so, does anything special have to be done?

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, isolation, switched-capacitor

I have an LTSpice simulation of a small switched-capacitor boost converter producing about 12W x 110V of DC, and I was wondering, does it have to be isolated (and need anything special to attain isolation, or is that only when getting input from line voltage)? Are there any required redundancies, like multiple capacitors in series, or required special capacitors like type-X and/or type-Y as used in an ATX power supply?

The circuit in question can be seen as a Dickson with alternating (push-pull) input:

(capacitors C4-C8 are a natural isolation barrier)

[image: Two stage Dickson switched-capacitor converter directly powering a string of 10 LED's with capacitors being the only connection between the powering circuit and the powered circuit.]

This circuit is representative, and a simplification.

Comment: I think  you are confusing AC inverters with DCDC charge pumps to create a negative DC from a positive DC https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/design-handbooks/Practical-Design-Techniques-Power-Thermal/Section4.pdf

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 -- I have changed my question per your observation from "inverter" to "boost converter" and added a screen shot of a simplification of the circuit in question. Do I add an additional capacitor in series with each line (one right after "AC1", and another right after "AC2")?  Will that keep the 110V from "breaking out" back into the 12V part of the circuit? Is this necessary, and is anything else necessary (or recommended, for safety)? Thanks.

Comment: Define "must". What are you going to use it for? LED driving as in your schematic? Is any part of the output user accessible? Your circuit itself could not be considered isolated.

Comment: I see no useful value in this concept without specs or simulation.  Nor do I see any safe use of components subject to line transients.  It is not efficient nor cost-effective with large C's to drive 10x 1 Ohm load LEDs which are also obsolete. It has poor power factor and is not safe.  Stick to programming.

Comment: Sorry for your loss, but this is not going to give useful results. I am not judging you, rather only this hypothetical offline design.   SMPS have inductive protection with clamps.

Comment: See for yourself. To get 12W avg. it needs to generate -143.6 VAR reactive watts with large plastic caps just to function. https://tinyurl.com/y457oof3

Comment: https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator/customize/206?noparams=0   12WDC from AC  Efficiency:
83%
BOM Cost:
$5.78
Footprint:
1689 mm²

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 -- I don't want to reveal too much about what I'm coming up with, but unfortunately, it seems to always come down to that I must reveal things concretely, or nobody can understand how to answer. Current LTSpice simulation parameters (and results) are:  All discrete BSS BJT, input 12V 1,518mA 18,337mW, out 110V 145mA 16,056mW, 87.6% effic, 5 stages, all 11 caps 47uF, at 20KHz, powering 37 white LED's. About 2-3% circuitry left out, signal generation. Thanks for the Falstad simulation. The Wbench didn't come up for some reason.

Comment: If you show spec in a question , then the question is maybe answerable.   but AC IN and 10 LED Out is not what you have now.TI requires a free registration to use WebBench.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Try [this Falstad](https://tinyurl.com/y5npovnf) simulation. On webench.ti, I'm currently logged-in. All Texas Instruments WBench says is "Oops! Something went wrong Sorry, an error occured with our website and someone has been notified to take a look."

Comment: I do not get an error from TI.  I also cannot make your attempt work.  It is simply not feasible to scale for > 1 W due to the huge ratio of reactive/real power requirements and the cost required to improve that is not desirable.https://tinyurl.com/y4bbymgh  It is only useful to power << 1 W

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 -- Here is a [modification of your circuit](https://tinyurl.com/y6knrbed) to produce the power output I wanted, which required deleting some LED's (the forward voltage is probably different from the one I chose in LTSpice4).  The output at the LED's is now about 180mA when steady state is reached.  Does this still have the "huge ratio of reactive/real power requirements"? Also, [for this circuit](https://tinyurl.com/y24mj9n3), I run it at 400Hz and added two 1uH inductors -- does that help at all? I can't play with hybrid converters if I don't understand the building blocks.

Comment: The power source must charge up a lot of energy in all those caps unlike SMSP which can get away with storing much less power and many have soft start. With 0.1 Ohms your start power is 2.4 kW and with 1 Ohm it is more like 100 W for a longer startup.  What did you have in mind to power this 20 W LED string?

Comment: Meanwell has designed a 25W constant adjustable current < 57V and Arrow sells them for $20 (1 of)  it's hard to beat that with all the features and compliance.  https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/XLG-25/XLG-25-SPEC.PDF  https://www.arrow.com/en/products/xlg-25-a/mean-well-enterprises

Comment: The answer is in the complete nonperiodicity of the sequence. I stumbled on it by trying to filter a boost converter with alternating inductors and capacitors. That would set up resonances, which I could not seem to get rid of. So then, what sequence of numbers has complete nonperiodicity? Caps of 100u and inductors according to the F. sequence, like 13u, 21u, 34u.  That created no resonances, and filtered the power very well, with high efficiency. Is that good enough to be able to assure others that I'm not grandstanding.

Comment: If it's truly isolated, then it could possibly serve as a Local MOSFET supply and therefore operate anywhere within the circuit.

Comment: What do you think?